# Where do I get the ChromeDriver.exe from? The download link isn't available

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

All the discussions and forums that I have looked at for help point to the following locations:

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

But both the pages are no longer available.

Any other way I can get to download the ChromeDriver.exe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download ChromeDriver.exe from the following URL:

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Patrick L for the help. :)
I figured out that the links weren't available since I was connected to my office network. I disconnected from the network and was able to download the .exe.

Comment: This link now goes to an older version (2.10). The latest is (as of writing) is 2.14. Bryn's link is more agnostic and will always take you to the most up to date version, use his not this

Answer (score 8):

The downloads are hosted here:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 0):

If you want a scripted way to always get the latest version you can get it using a package manager like [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/) or [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver)

```
nuget install Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver -ExcludeVersion
```

Will drop the latests chromedriver in a folder below our current location based on platform, e.g. for windows it would be `\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver\driver\win32\chromedriver.exe`

You could do something similar with the [latest chromedriver from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver)

```
npm install chromedriver
```

And if you need a particular version both package manager support version command arguments